# Routting error in rails-cpanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cpanel

I deployed rails application in cPanel and run rails project but always server return to me this error:

> No route matches "/index.html.var" with {:method=>:get}

http://railsbama.tk/

Notice: this project is hello world and has one controller('home') and one action 'index' only return 'hello world'.

Comment: please provide your routes file

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your root path to the controller and action: `root to: 'home#index'`